# You can make this conversion explicit by writing `as' Exception

Tags: scala, parsing, io, implicit, circe

I'm trying to decode `IO[Response]` returned into  `IO[List[T]]` note that the decoder is in the scope.
here what I tried :

```
   def getRequest[T](path: String)(implicit decoder: Decoder[List[T]]): IO[List[T]] = {
    val requestUrl: String = Request.queryString(s"$path")
    val request = RequestBuilder().url(requestUrl).buildGet()

    responseHandling(IO(httpClient(request)).toIO).as[List[T]]
  }

 def responseHandling(response: IO[Response]): IO[Response] = ???
```

but I'm having this error returned :
//

```
missing argument list for method as in class IO
                       [error] Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
                       [error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `as _` or `as(_)` instead of `as`.
                       [error]     responseHandling(IO(httpClient(request)).toIO).as[List[T]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to perform an operation on the `Response` instead of on the `IO`, so you'll have to `map` it.

```
responseHandling(IO(httpClient(request)).toIO).map(_.as[List[T]])
```

I also doubt `toIO` is necessary since you already wrapped the result of `httpClient(request)` in `IO`. So that should be a no-op. I would actually expect `httpClient(request)` itself to return an `IO`, but I don't know which library you're using here.

Comment: totally agree with you, first httpClient(request) returns IO[Future[Response]], using twitter.finagle library. hense the use of toIO. 2) when I map over response I .as is not recognized and I have as import proposition import com.twitter.bijection.Conversion.asMethod and this as well returns an error could not find implicit value for parameter conv: com.twitter.bijection.Conversion[com.twitter.finagle.http.Response,List[T]]

Comment: @MunqAr for what I can see after a quick googling, there is not out of the box support for **circe** in **twitter-bijection**, so not sure how you expected this to work. Also, if the problem is just the conversion it self then everything on the question is meaningless, the problem is unrelated to `IO`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding brackets to toIO... i.e. .toIO()?

Comment: not sure, but when I added the () , it says unspecified value parameters ec: executionContext